# What PYTHONPATH should I setup in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, pythonpath

This is really bugging me.

Here is my hierarchy for the folder that contains Dockerfile.

```
server
    - __init__.py
    - nlp
        - core.py
    - Dockerfile
    - server.py
```

Here is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

# Pull the environment name out of the environment.yml
RUN echo "source activate $(head -1 environment.yml | cut -d' ' -f2)" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/$(head -1 environment.yml | cut -d' ' -f2)/bin:$PATH

RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc" && /opt/conda/envs/rdqcc_nlp/bin/python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

ENV PATH "/opt/conda/envs/rdqcc_nlp/bin/python:${PATH}"
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/src/app:/usr/src/app/nlp"

CMD ["/opt/conda/envs/rdqcc_nlp/bin/python", "server.py"]
```

And here is how I import the nlp module in `server.py`.

```
from .nlp.core import NLP
```

I also tried

```
from server.nlp.core import NLP
```

but the same error poped up with 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.nlp'; '__main__' is not a package`
or 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'server.nlp'; '__main__' is not a package`

Did I setup the wrong `PYTHONPATH`? What should I do? By the way I used `docker-compose` to call the service built from `server` folder.

Comment: you can `echo` envvars and `sys.path` and `ls` directory structure to diagnose this...

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thanks for the advise. Do you know what exactly does `PYTHONPATH ` do? Since everything works fine with me in Pycharm, I am wondering how to fill the gap between docker and PyCharm.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the Dockerfile on the wrong level. When files gets copied in, you get:

- `/usr/src/app/__init__.py`
- `/usr/src/app/nlp/`
- ...

etc.

So:

Move Dockerfile so it's at same level as `server/` (`cd server; mv Dockerfile ..`) if you're on Linux/Mac:

- `Dockerfile`
- `server/__init__.py`
- `server/nlp/`
- ...

And then you can just do `from server import whatever` in your code, and it'll import from the server package. E.g. `from server import server` will import server.py.